# Write cookie to client local machine in c#

Tags: c#, cookies

I have a `page A` which generates another `page B's` URL with a query string containing encrypted authorization information to access to that `page B`.

When a user use that URL to access to the `page B`, I want to write a cookie with the authorization information into the user's local machine.

I read the `MSDN` reference and it does mention cookies can be generated and read through request and response, but is there a way to write the cookie to a specific location?

Is there also a way I can check whether there's already an existing cookie in the user's local machine before I generate my cookie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Page A and Page B both under the same domain name (ex: `www.example.com/PageA` and `www.example.com/PageB`)?

Comment: No, they are not under the same domain name.

Comment: Are you wanting to check and write the cookies from page B? My reading is that you want to, when page B is accessed, check if a cookie exists and write one if not. Is Page A going to be involved in this process or is that just being talked about for context?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check nor set cookies that are not under the same domain as the site performing the request.

You can only set or read cookies for the [Same Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as the site that is the setting the cookie. This is a security feature built in to HTML and can not be worked around.

For a easy to understand example of why this is this way, would you like `www.myEvilSiteThatStealsYourData.com` to be able to read or write cookies for `www.theBankingWebsiteYouUse.com`?

Comment: Hey that's the bank I use... Does the Same Origin policy only apply to browsers?

Comment: @Nate Same Origin is considered part of the "cookie" spec, see [section 4.1.2.3 `The Domain Attribute`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3) "*The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin server.*" So anything that follows rfc6265 would also need to follow Same Origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

Url in page A should contain encrypted UserID and Timestamp symmetrically encrypted ,(like /B?SecurityToken=blabla), page B has to decrypt the security token, verify Timestamp is not too old (1 minute should be enough) and create cookie based on decrypted security token.

More robust scenario: A (identity provider) send user to B (service provider) without any token whatsoever; B checks if user have authentication cookie in B domain, if he does not, B redirects user to A's single login handler, if user have authentication cookie in A domain, A sends encrypted response to B, providing info about user (like UserID) otherwise A asks user for credentials, and if they're correct A sends encrypted response to B. B decrypt the UserID and creates authentication cookie in B domain. There are also protocols for this (SAML, OAuth) - in similar way you can use facebook or google to do identity provider for your app.

Comment: Thanks, Ondrei Svejdar. I understand the risk. In my case my two domain are co-relating and I have full control on both of them. By generating the URL in page A I mean the URL is generated and used a pop up window to display it to the user and user needs to manually copy this URL and open a browser, paste the URL to navigate to page B. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Copy paste shouldn't make a difference, I would just make the timestamp valid for longer period (min 5 minutes).